# Is Sachi the name of a position or person?

Tags: indra

It is well known fact in Hinduism that Indra is a person in a position and is not the name of a person. A person gets the position by his deeds.

Is Sachi same as Indra? I mean, is Sachi a person in a position or it is the name of a female person?

Comment: All these 'post' definitions come from secterians to denigrate other gods.Some Kavirpanthis are now saying that Vishnu and Ishwara all are posts--u cd check on youtube.

Comment: @hanugm When Nahusha was made Indra, he asked to be with Sachi and that eventually led to him getting removed from that post. So I think it's not a post.

Comment: "Is Sachi the name of a position or person?" Both

Answer (score 1):

According to the Jyotisha-sastra, the answer must be : These are names of Devataas and not posts.

Because, Indra and Sachi are the Devata and Pratyadhi-Devata of the planet 'Sukra'. And Sukra is a very very important planet in astrology.

If these two are posts, then the Devata and Pratyadhi-Devata of all other planets would also be reckoned as post, like Narayana and Vishnu are Adhi-Devata and Pratyadhi-Devata of Budha, Agni and Shiva are of Ravi, Agni and Skanda are of Mangala, Yama and Brahmaa are of Sani etc.

((Reference-Nityakarma-Paddhati-Shyamacharan Kaviratna)

Comment: You are saying that **Indra is also not a post** right?

Comment: @hanugm its what Jyotisha-sastra vachanas imply

Comment: This is a smart approach of addressing the problem :D @Partha